# Select second record from table matching with first record

Tags: php, mysql, match

How select first record and matching with second record ?!

Samlpe:

```
1- A
2- A
3- B
4- C
```

This code match 1 and 2 , and return TRUE

How write query ?!

Comment: Yes , i want check last column and last-1 column for multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ID's of the rows that have the duplicate values on the second column you can do:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,t2.id
FROM tab1 t1
INNER JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1.val = t2.val AND t1.id <> t2.id;
```

To get TRUE when there are at least two rows that have the same value on the second column you or FALSE otherwise, you can do:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN numEquals <> 0 THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE' END AS HasEquals
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS numEquals
  FROM tab1 t1
  INNER JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1.val = t2.val AND t1.id <> t2.id
  ) a
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f77be2/13)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

basic sql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = column2 LIMIT 1
```

in php you can do the check

Comment: if last and last-1 column ?!